# Argument of \sf@@@subfloat has an extra } - what is it?

Tags: errors, subfloats

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[Funkcja $f(x)=\sin(x)$ jest ciągła.]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{funkcja_ciagla}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[Funkcja $f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2 & x \leqslant  0\\1-x & x>0\protect\end{cases}$ jest nieciągła -- nie da się jej narysować nie odrywając ołówka od kartki (zauważ też, że $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}f(x)=0\neq 1=\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}f(x)$).]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{funkcja_nieciagla}}
\end{figure}
```

Why does this code produce the error:

```
Argument of \sf@@@subfloat has an extra }. ...s[width=0.5\textwidth]{funkcja_nieciagla}}
```

What does this error mean? How can I work around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your second `\subfloat` with the `cases` environment in the caption. The optional parameter serves two purposes: To determine the caption and to provide the text for the list of floats. Moving the text to the list of floats does not work well for the `cases` environment.

Solution: Provide a separate text for the list of floats (e.g., the empty text if you don't have such a list), by using the second optional argument of `\subfloat`. In fact, it doesn't make sense anyway to have the `cases` environment in the list of floats.

```
\subfloat[Text for list of floats, if any]%
         [Text for caption]%
         {Body of subfigure}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat
    []% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    [Funkcja
    $f(x)= \begin{cases}x^2 & x \leqslant 0\\1-x & x>0 \end{cases}$
    jest nieciągła -- nie da się jej narysować nie odrywając ołówka od
    kartki (zauważ też, że
    $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}f(x)=0\neq
    1=\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow
      0^{+}}f(x)$).%
    ]%
    {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, when trying to insert an itemize environment in the subfloat caption like this:

```
\subfloat[some text \begin{itemize} \item{one} \item{two} \end{itemize}]{\includegraphics...}
```

that gave me the error:

> Argument of \sf@@@subfloat has an extra }

simply rewriting like gernot suggested:

```
\subfloat[][some text \begin{itemize} \item{one} \item{two} \end{itemize}]{\includegraphics...}
```

did the job!